# function onLocationChanged is called only once

Tags: java, android

I found Google Maps tutorial. I rewrite everything from tutorial and it works fine, but... I want to catch my gps position if it changes. I have overrided function "onLocationChanged" but this function is only called for first time when i start my program on Android emulator. Do I use a good function?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
Context context = this;

Double getLatitude;
Double getLongitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //permission is granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (client == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else    //permission is denied
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { //<- THIS CODE IS CALLED ONLY ONCE, WHAT FUNCTION I MUST OVERRIDE TO CATCH LATLNG CHANGE EVERYTIME?
    lastLocation = location;

    if (currentLocationMarker != null) {
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    getLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    getLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    /*
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Aktualna Pozycja");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    */
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

    if(client != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }
}

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}



@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: If you wana get multiple GPS updates then **you obviously should not unregister from getting 'em ...**

Comment: I think your `requestLocationUpdates` is running only once.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? When i start program i get my gps position in variables: getLatitude and getLongitude. If i change gps position i see on emulator that dot on map is correctly change. But idk in what function i can catch it.

Comment: @Selvin mean , what you think `removeLocationUpdates` will do?

Comment: Thanks. I do not hide that i rewrite everything from youtube and i skipped this line, when i analize this.